# What happened if there is "record = State" in handle_call function?

Tags: erlang, gen-server

The handle_call function in gen_server is :

```
Module:handle_call(Request, From, State) -> Result
```

But I meet one handle_call function like this：

```
handle_call(info, _From, #yuv{decoder = undefined} = State) ->
  {reply, [], State};

handle_call(info, _From, #yuv{decoder = Decoder} = State) ->
  {reply, av_decoder:info(Decoder), State};

handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
  {noreply, ok, State}.
```

I want to know what happened ? It's above my head

BTW: The yuv record is :

```
-record(yuv, {
  host,
  name,
  media,
  decoder,
  consumer
}).
```

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly, you do not understand what the following pattern does:

```
foo(#bar{buz = Value} = Record) -> ...
```

This is a common way to pattern match against whole and part of a function argument. In my example the variable `Value` will hold the value of the field `buz` and the variable `Record` will hold the value of the whole record. This can be applied in other cases, like:

```
foo([Head|Tail] = List) -> ...
foo({First, Second} = Tuple) -> ...
```

and so on. Instead of variables you can use literals and then the pattern matching will succeed only if the same literal appears in the call.

In your example:

```
handle_call(info, _From, #yuv{decoder = undefined} = State) ->
  {reply, [], State};

handle_call(info, _From, #yuv{decoder = Decoder} = State) ->
  {reply, av_decoder:info(Decoder), State};

handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
  {noreply, ok, State}.
```

The first pattern matches if the `decoder` field's value is `undefined` and then the reply is `[]`. The second matches all the other cases for `decoder` and replies with the value returned by the function. In both cases `State` is not modified and is passed "as is" back to the internal gen_server handlers.

Answer (score 1):

if the record yuv is defined as:

`-record(yuv, {
  decoder,
  foo,
  bar,
  baz
}).`

the form:

`handle_call(info, _From, #yuv{decoder = undefined} = State) ->
  {reply, [], State};`

is just sugar for:

`handle_call(info, _From, {yuv, undefined, _, _, _} = State) ->
  {reply, [], State};`

the match in the head of the function is exactly what you'd expect, it's just attempting to match the record defined in the function head to the record `State` wh